# Why does a wireless network give a more accurate location than a wired network?

Tags: wireless-networking, geolocation, network-location

I build a simple HTML5 website that takes my location (in latitude-longitude), and simply shows my location in Google maps.

I opened the HTML document with my laptop *Asus K53E-B1* and I found that when I connected to a wireless network, it showed almost my precise location (about 100 meter of inaccuracy), 
while when I plug in the network cable, and test again, it's a bit Inaccurate. (showed a street 12KM away from me).

Can you explain me why is a wireless network gives more accurate location?

Tested with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the cable, all they have to go on is public records like the ones you can find on [IP2Location](http://ip2location.com/). When you're using the wireless network, they can pick up a lot of information from the air. It's not just, as the other answer is implying, a matter of a public access point already being known.

The geolocation service also takes into account other networks in your vicinity (that you are not connected to) based on their SSID, MAC address and strength. If both you and your neighbor are using the geolocation service, and both of you see networks x, y and z, Google's service can draw the conclusion that you are located physically close to each other. It does this with a lot of data collected from users, which enables them to correlate your location rather well. I'm sure Google Street View vans are helping collect data from access points for this purpose as well.

Google explains how the service works [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en). However this page now has a less detailed description than it used to, but there's a copy of the old text [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213669/593264).

And consequently, if you are, for privacy reasons, not comfortable with the service sending a list of access points in your neighborhood to Google, you should obviously not use this service.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the wired network the accuracy is limited by your ISP, usually you get the address of some network center.

When you are using a (possibly public) WiFi-net the location of that accesspoint will be known already through others (who may have had GPS enabled) and so your location has to be within reach of that AP.